# salesforce Org synchronisation using talend

Tags: java, salesforce, etl, talend

I am working on a Salesforce project and I am doing the data integration using Talend. Throughout the integration I have several testing orgs. I would like to automate the comparison and migration of data of one org to another.

I made a job that connects to two orgs simultaneously, compares the data and migrates it. For a custom object I need 2 comparisons (A->B and B->A) for two orgs. I have 4 orgs which sums up to 8 comparisons. Since I have more than 50 objects the comparisons would sum up to over 400. This would take me a week to create.

I would like to simplify that if possible. Maybe to have the names of the orgs in an Excel file, for instance, with the connection parameters and that do some mapping and this way dynamically establish connections on the orgs and objects.

If there is some programming required it's not a problem.

Comment: What connection parameters do you need to connect do a different Salesforce organisation? Is it just a different URL? I've not used Salesforce before but have a good idea of how to approach this.

Comment: URL, username, password, ... and some others. About 10 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you always have 2 connections to compare between then you could, as you suggested in your question, store the connections in an Excel file or any other source that Talend can read. In this example I've decided to use a simple CSV.

Assuming you only need URL, username and password you would set up a CSV like so:

[image: Connection parameters in CSV]

Obviously you can easily add more columns to this as long as you duplicate the columns across both comparators.

In the Talend job you'll want to read this data in, iterate row by row to the rest of your job:

[image: Job layout]

Passing the relevant connection parameters to each of your Salesforce components:

[image: tSalesforceConnection_1]
[image: tSalesforceConnection_2]

Comment: I thougn my self something exactly like that. looks amazing